# Как открыть notepad сразу с текстом

Tags: windows, cmd

Мне нужно через окно "`выполнить`" выполнить команду `notepad`, откроется блокнот, но можно ли сразу прописать в окно "`выполнить`" команду `notepad текст` тоесть открыть блокнос сразу с текстом, который указали в окне "`выполнить`"

Comment: Ответ: можно. Для систем исполнения скриптов (Powershell/WSH/batch-file) запихиваем в конвейер соответствующие команды.

Comment: Наверное тебе нужен `autoit`.

Answer (score -1):

Такое возможно используя параметр `-qn="<text>"`.
Например, `notepad++.exe -qn="Я открыл файл с записанным текстом"`.
Можно также использовать параметр `-qt="<text>"`. Он открывает файл и записывает текст как пользователь, то есть по символам.

Полный список команд можно посмотреть [в мануале](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/command-prompt/)

**UPDATE:**
Раз речь о простом блокноте, то как вариант:

```
Echo "Этот текст введён из командной строки">*path*\test2.txt | timeout 5 | notepad *path*\test2.txt
```

Comment: Мне кажется Вы дали ссылку не на тот продукт. Как я понял, автор задал вопрос о встроенном Windows-приложении `notepad.exe`. Вы дали ссылку на `notepad++`

Comment: @Daemon-5, тогда как вариант, то создать батник. В нём создаётся файл, вставляется текст по параметру и открывается файл. Из cmd вызывать батник и передавая ему параметр

Comment: @Daemon-5, `Echo "Этот текст введён из командной строки">*path*\test2.txt | timeout 5 | notepad *path*\test2.txt`